# Cardinality of Type in a given universe

Tags: lean, lean3, set-theory, universe, universe-polymorphism

I'm trying to determine the cardinality of `Type u` in Lean 3. So far I've been able to prove two inequalities:

1. `univ.{u u+1} ≤ # (Type u)` (using `quotient.out` as an injection from cardinals to types)

2. `lift.{u+2} (# (Type u)) < univ.{u+1 u+2}` (as `# (Type u)` is a cardinal in `u + 1`, and the universal cardinal of a given universe level is greater than all other cardinals in that level)

So I know that the cardinality of `Type u` is greater than or equal to the universal cardinal of `u` and less than the universal cardinal of `u + 1`. However, I'm wondering if I can narrow it down further. I suspect it might be equal to `univ.{u}`, but I don't know how to prove it.

Does anyone have any hints as to how to narrow down the cardinality of `Type u`?

Comment: We reached the same conclusions in this thread on Zulip: https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/116395-maths/topic/The.20cardinal.20.60.23.28Type.20u.29.60 
I expect that `univ.{u u+1} = # (Type u)` is independent of Lean. Almost anything that talks about equality of types is independent of Lean. For example, I wouldn't be surprised if `# {A : Type u // is_empty A } > univ.{u u+1}` is consistent with Lean.

Comment: @FlorisvanDoorn you can probably craft a model where this inequality holds using some flavour of the "times bool" model of MLTT (see Section 5.1 from [this paper](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01445835/document)), by replacing bool by some adequate type. AFAIK the model is simple enough to scale to all the extensions from the Lean type theory, including choice and whatnot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Equality is not provable. Indeed, it is consistent that `univ.{u u+1} < #(Type u)` at every level `u`.

Recall that the universe level operations that Lean allows are quite limited. (See [Mario Carneiro, *The Type Theory of Lean*](https://github.com/digama0/lean-type-theory/releases), for all the details.) The level terms are built from universe variables using only: `0`, `∙+1`, `max(∙,∙)` and `imax(∙,∙)`. Because these operations are so limited, it is possible to give nontrivial self-interpretations of Lean's type theory in itself.

Let `f` be any strictly increasing function from levels to levels such that `f(0) = 0`. Consider the interpretation of Lean in itself where `Sort u` is reinterpreted as `Sort f(u)`. Thus the new universe levels are only those in the range of `f` and the successor operation `∙+1` is reinterpreted so that `f(u)+1` is now `f(u+1)`. Everything in Lean's type theory works as-is with just a few exceptions. For example, `Sort u : Sort u+1` doesn't work on-the-nose; similarly with some inductive types. There's a couple of different ways to patch this, the details are immaterial. (If Lean's type theory were cumulative there would essentially be nothing to fix.)

Now consider this self-interpretation where, for example, `f(0)=0`, `f(1) = 1`, ..., `f(42) = 42` but `f(43) = 44`, `f(44) = 45`, etc. In this interpretation, `Type 41` (= `Sort 42`) is unchanged but `Type 42` is now the old `Type 43`. It follows that `univ.{41 42}` (which is basically the old `univ.{41 43}`) is strictly smaller than `#(Type 42)` (which is the old `#(Type 43)`). This is because the *original* `univ.{42 43}` and `#(Type 42)` still exists in between these two cardinals, even though they have lost their particular meaning in the new interpretation.

Comment: I guess the moral here is that one shouldn't think of `Type (u+1)` as the next universe after `Type u` but rather as the next _designated_ universe; there might be plenty of could-be universes in between that have no special designation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!